# How is animation accomplished in these apps?

Tags: android

Most of the Android users use the [GO SMS](http://www.talkandroid.com/23387-go-sms-for-android-is-a-clean-alternative-sms-app/) app, and the iPhone users use their normal messaging app (Android rocks). Now, whenever a user types a message and presses the send button, the message's edit text field sets a glossy green background, also the green colored background comes floating at the back of the edit text field. How do they do it?

(I have been searching this for a while, but was unable to find an answer.)

Comment: I don't think _most_ android users use GO SMS.

Comment: @Keyser , that was not the topic, the question is how do they do that?

Comment: I know it was. And it was a comment and not an answer.